# Value not being return

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm unable to figure out why no values are being returned

```
   @wire(getActiveAppsInBox, { boxKey: '$boxId' })
    wiredApps(result) {
        if (result.data) {


            var promises = result.data.map(function (item) {
                let version = getLatesVersion({ appKey: item.Released_App__c })
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log('data: ' + data[0].Name);
                        return data[0].Name;
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log('Error: ', error);
                    });
                console.log('version: ' + JSON.stringify(version));
                return { ...item, version }

            });

            console.log("promises: " + JSON.stringify(promises));
        }
    }
```

output:

```
version: {}
promises: [{"Id":"a050i000000JuFdAAK","Release_App__c":"a030i000000uQ9SXAU","Release_App__r":{"Name":"Amazing App","Id":"a030i000000uQ9SXAU"},"version":{}}]
data: 1.11.0
```

expected result:

```
version: 1.11.0
promises: [{"Id":"a050i000000JuFdAAK","Release_App__c":"a030i000000uQ9SXAU","Release_App__r":{"Name":"Amazing App","Id":"a030i000000uQ9SXAU"},"version":"1.11.0"}]
data: 1.11.0
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: The order of your debugs has the answer here. Your call to `getLatesVersion` is asynchronous, so the first two debugs (ergo, assignments) occur before your data is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous, so you need to wait for their results. Here's one way you could fix that:

```
let promises = result.data.map(datum => getLatestVersion({appKey:datum.Released_App__c}));
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  result.data = result.data.map((item,index) => ({...item, version: results[index].Name }));
});
```